# Render R markdown from a function

Tags: r, r-markdown

I need to automate some report generation. I would like to create an `rmarkdown` report from a function, something like

```
make_report <- function(file_path = "data_file.txt", outfile){

    # get data from external file
    object <- parse_text(file_path)

    # ?pass it into report template?
    rmarkdown::render("report_template.Rmd", outfile)
}
```

Where `report_template.Rmd` prints tables and figures based on the information in the `data_frame` object. I've seen ways to make [rmarkdown templates](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html), but I don't know if there is a way to pass anything into them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly pass objects to `render` function, but you still can save objects into RDS/csv and load them in your rmarkdown file at the beginning in the hidden section, so it will not be printed to your output document.

Comment: I just wondered (as in while reading your answer) if `render()` can look at the current environment. That might solve my problem...

Comment: if so you may try to pass object by setting it into some option: `options("my_obj" = my_obj)`. I'm using such way when I need to pass object to shiny apps.